# how to automate mulitple websites through a website user interface

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webautomation

My goal is to provide a web-based user interface, i.e. a form to fill out on a web page, which then can be used to open multiple other websites to fill in the information entered, which includes clicking on various buttons, etc.  I have done this with Selenium via an interface written in Python that uses Chrome as the browser, but that requires installing Python, chromedriver, etc. on a user's machine.

The analogy is how one searches for an airline flight: a user enters the travel information one time on a home webpage and the site then opens multiple other sites to find the prices.

From what I gather, enabling this automation from within a browser would require having Selenium installed and available on a host server...is this correct, or is there another way to achieve this?

thx